# Parent of smaller height than child element

Tags: html, css, position, height, html-lists

I am trying to make something akin to the side-menu on [this website](http://www.thecapitol.pn).
I am currently experiencing a problem with the height of the #parent list element, since I would like it to be of the exact same height as that of its content (the #child span - see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La5vafh6/)).

```
<body>
<article class="full-height row">
    <nav id="nav-container" class="full-height row col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-sm-4 full-height"></div>
        <ul id="nav-button" class="col-sm-8 full-height vcenter">
            <li class="vcentered active"><span class="fontastic">0</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="nav-navbar" class="col-sm-8 full-height display-none">
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Passions</li>
            <li>Close</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
    </section>
    <canvas class="full-height"></canvas>
</article></body>
```

The #child element does not have any css positioning specified, nor does it have a z-index or float property, hence it should not be removed from its context. I don't understand why the #child element is taller than its #parent.

This was performed under Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: You have a runnable snippet (nice), but it runs nothing. There is nothing to see.

Comment: CMPS: jsfiddle created. The question is now simpler and shorter.
GolezTrol: Solved, see fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/La5vafh6/1/)**

The reason for the child to be taller than the parent is that the font class `fontastic` has `line-height = 1`. In other words the child is telling the parent my line height is 1, but in fact it's is taking more. To fix this, you can set `line-height = 1.2`

Answer (score 0):

The `<span>` tag is inside `<li>` tag. Your concern is about the height which is actually due to the font size of text that is `64px.` As far as your concern about spacing between `<li>` and its content, it is the default minimum spacing between `<li>` and its content. There is no problem in your code. I tried and consumed half hour on your code but could not reduce the default spacing. Hope it is clear.

**EDIT:**

I dont see anything in jsfiddle therefore i created an html in dreamweaver and output in firefox and i dont see what you say that `span` is greater than `font-size` You can see in the image below

[image: <code>span border</code> is red and <code>li border</code> is blue and <code>0</code> is at its <code>font size</code> that is <code>64px</code>]

Comment: See the jsfiddle I added, the li is less tall than the character in the span element.

Comment: see edited answer above. I set border of span and li to solid with red and blue color respectively

Comment: The viewport is simply too small in the jsfiddle. You need to extend the size of the result window so that the menu is displayed (@media(min-size = 768px)).

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` has a border of 1 px, which the parent `li` picks up in its calculation of the height.
In my case the `span` has 73px height (size of the content "0" with font) and the `li` has 74px height (span's content + span's border).

Comment: In the jsfiddle that is now provided in the OP, the height of the li is of 64px whereas the span is of 73px. Hence the span is taller than the li, not the opposite.